# this jQuery code worked before it didn't now why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prestashop

I have this code which animates an image and moves it in the cart. It worked before, but it doesn't anymore since I have updated PrestaShop to the last version (1.7.7.1)

Here's the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: imgtodrag.clone(...).offset(...).css is not a function

What could cause that?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-cart', function() {
  if ($(document).width() > 767) {
    /*console.log("animation from outside of ajax");*/
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 90) {
      var cart = $('.cart-menu');
    } else {
      var cart = $('#_desktop_cart');
    }
    var imgtodrag = $(this).closest('.product-miniature').find(".thumbnail-container").find("img").eq(0);
    if (imgtodrag.lenght != 0) {
      var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone().offset({
        top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
        left: imgtodrag.offset().left
      }).css({
        'opacity': '0.5',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'height': '150px',
        'width': '150px',
        'z-index': '100'
      }).appendTo($('body')).animate({
        'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
        'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
        'width': 75,
        'height': 75
      }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

      setTimeout(function() {
        cart.effect("shake", {
          times: 2
        }, 200);
      }, 1500);

      imgclone.animate({
        'width': 0,
        'height': 0
      }, function() {
        $(this).detach()
      });
      console.log("test2");
    }
  } else {
```

**Edit : it seems that this part :**

```
.offset({
            top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
            left: imgtodrag.offset().left
          })
```

**don't work.
 same thing if i put random values instead of "top: imgtodrag.offset().top" and "left: imgtodrag.offset().left",
 i verified if i could get values from imgtodrag and yes i can,

So it seems that my imgtodrag.clone() can't work with the offset function, i don't understand why**

Comment: I can't tell you what the issue is without seeing a working example, however I can tell you that `if (imgtodrag)` will always be `true` as `imgtodrag` is a jQuery object, which will always coerce to a truthy value. You probably need a `if (imgtodrag.length != 0)` check in there instead.

Comment: Also use `$(this).closest('.product-miniature')` and not `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent('.product-miniature')`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: imgtodrag.clone(...).offset(...).css is not a function` It's very likely that you're cloning something inexistent. Check comment above by @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Thank you guys, i changed my code with your suggestions but i have the same error, here's an exemple of the working code : https://codepen.io/webrajendra/pen/yYoqpM

Comment: The error seems to come from .offset({
        top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
        left: imgtodrag.offset().left
      })

Comment: i tried different values to set the offset instead of the var "imgtodrag", but i have the same issue, i really don't understand why it don't want to work with the "offset" function :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the offset, i just took the values of the offsets top and left and put them in the css part like that :

```
var topoff = Math.round(imgtodrag.offset().top);
var leftoff = Math.round(imgtodrag.offset().left);

var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .css({
                    'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100',
                    'top' : topoff + 'px',
                    'left' : leftoff + 'px',
                }).appendTo($('body'))
                    .animate({
                    'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
                }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

The result is the same :)